# How to call javascript method on after multiple selection of select box

Tags: javascript

Previously I used onchange event to call javascript method(in this method used AJAX call to pass selected option to server). But this leads to multiple AJAX call to server on multiple options selection. Is there a way to call javascript method after making multiple selection in select box so that I can prevent multiple AJAX calls to server.

Comment: Just call AJAX after the onchange event. SO basically select all the options , store it in a variable and then call AJAX later and pass the variables

Comment: use setTimeout function in onchange handler. When the time has come and no one onchange events has fired than send data to server, otherwise call setTimeout again. This logic uses in autocomplete fields.

Comment: @Mohit, but how could we know when user completes the selection and after that to make ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

here it will abort in process ajax request and will consider only last request..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchInput").onchange(function(){
        ajaxSelect( $("#searchInput").val() );
    });
});

var request;
function ajaxSelect(selectedKey) {
    /* if request is in-process, kill it */
    if(request) {
        request.abort();
    };

    request = $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://example.com/ajaxRequestHandler/",
        data: "action=selectmulti&selectedKey=" + selectedKey
    }).done(function() {
        /* process response */

        /* response received, reset variable */
        request = null;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks prashant, but I am using prototype.js for ajax where we do not have any option to abort the request.

Comment: @AnilGoud `abort` is plain js method of `xhr` object

Answer (score 0):

one way could be to define following event clearly.

> after making multiple selection in select box

You can think of using other events like onblur or onmouseout on select box to send ajax request if that suits your need.